# Definition of the omega-limit set

Tags: calculus, limits, dynamical-systems

The $\omega$-limit set of the set  $B$ is defined as $\omega(B) = \bigcap_{n \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{k \geq n} T^k(B) }$, where $T$ is some continuous mapping.

What is the intuition behind this definition? I found this image in the Wiggins's book "Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos" and it shows that the $\omega$-limit set of point $x$ is a point $x_0$ on the curve $\gamma$):

[image]

To me, it is clear  that  $y \in \omega(B) $ iff there exists sequence  $x_j \in B$ and sequence of integers $n_j \rightarrow \infty$  such that $T^{n_j} x_j  \rightarrow y  $  as $j \rightarrow \infty$. But I don't completely understand the definition from beginning, why do we need union and then intersection? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to real analysis, in set theory, we have the concept of the $\lim \sup S_i$ [of a sequence of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) $S_i$.

In general,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup A_n := \bigcap_{n\geq1}\bigcup_{i\geq n} A_i$$

A helpful phrase for the members of $\lim \sup A_n$ (at least for me) is that $a \in \lim \sup A_n$ are members of the sequence that are appear *infinitely often*.

We need the union part because it's not guaranteed that the $A_i$ are a monotonic sequence of sets. If so, we normally can dispense with the union.

Now, on to your variant:

$$\omega(B) = \bigcap_{n \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{k \geq n} T^k(B) }$$

Here we are defining the $\omega-$limit as the $\lim \sup$ of the *[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_operator)* of all the values visited after at least $k$ applications of the transformation $T$ on the starting set $B$.

Comparing to the general $\lim \sup$ of a set, we have $A_i = T^k(B)$ with the added piece that we are taking the closure of the union -- I'm guessing to cover the case where the points in $B$ converge asymptotically to the $\omega-$limit (which I suspect is usually the case in real applications).

In the case of the drawing $\gamma$ appears to be limit set of the dynamical system. It is the set to which all point visit infinitely often and/or converge to.

Comment: Just one question: should it be limsup instead of liminf in your definition?

Comment: And also, if it's limsup, could you please modify the interpretation

Comment: @User154 lol - yes! Will flip the terms …

Comment: @User154 — corrected